# Database email to know the history of backups

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I need to send an email by listing different types of backups, time of backups, summary of these backups, backup file path and name of backup with the help of database email. Can anyone help me with a script for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched online, it is easy to find such script

Comment: @leeg4625, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in my job i send email report with HTML.

I get the script that @leeg4625 points

I hope thats works for you

```
declare @html varchar(max)
set @html='<h1>My Backup Report</h1>
<table border="1";><tr><td><b>Server</b></td><td><b>database_name</b></td><td><b>backup_start_date</b></td><td><b>backup_finish_date</b></td><td><b>expiration_date</b></td>
<td><b>backup_type</b></td><td><b>backup_size</b></td><td><b>logical_device_name</b></td><td><b>physical_device_name</b></td><td><b>backupset_name</b></td><td><b>description</b></td></tr>'

SELECT 
@html=@html+'<tr><td>'+CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername'))+'</td><td>'
+isnull(msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(convert(varchar,msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,103),'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(convert(varchar,msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date,103),'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(convert(varchar,msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date,103),'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(CASE msdb..backupset.type 
WHEN 'D' THEN 'Database' 
WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log' 
END,'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(convert(varchar,msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size),'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(msdb.dbo.backupset.name,'')+'</td><td>'
+isnull(msdb.dbo.backupset.description,'')+'</td><td></tr>'
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
WHERE (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 7) 
ORDER BY 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'email1@domain.com;email2@domain.com',
    @body = @htm,
    @body_format='HTML',
    @subject = 'Backup Report'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various SQL scripts available online, for eg: one can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1601/script-to-retrieve-sql-server-database-backup-history-and-no-backups/) to retrieve the backup history and then use [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190307.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to send the email for the retrieved backup history as needed by scheduling it via SQL agent job.

However, the method that i have been using is to make use of Powershell to send such reports as described here [Use PowerShell to Report SQL Server Backup Status](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/02/use-powershell-to-report-sql-server-backup-status/)

You can save the above script and execute it manually whenever you need to. However, to get the most out of it, its recommended scheduling it daily by using SQL Server Agent. Doing this will give you early notification of issues and allow you to act quickly to get those databases backed up.